# Content dependent on combobox

Tags: usability, filter, dynamic-ui, relations

I have just tested my solution and can conclude that the users overlook the combobox that decide what type of filter that will be shown underneath - interval (Take a look at the picture)

I have thought about moving the combobox into the area underneath the "interval" - but if you choose another filter type the title will change, - i think it will be confusing?

[image: Content dependent on combobox]

Comment: Why not just move the combobox to the title bar?

Comment: @Blam Because the top title bar depend on the filter type - if you select interval, from list, ect.

Comment: If the title is the selected value then why do you need a separate title?  I look at that screen and see the same information twice.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 3 items in the drop-down (interval, comparison, options), couldn't you could display them in tabs instead of a drop down?

**Example 1**
[image]

**Example 2**

[image]

**Example 3**
[image]

This won't work if you've got more than a few items in your drop-down. Also I'm wondering if those numbered boxes at the top of your screen are tabs or steps. If there are tabs then you probably can't have tabs twice.

Comment: Thanks for the very visual answer..nice! My problem is that the user will have a list of the columns on the left to select the column they want to add a filter to. depending on that column will the possibilities in the drop down change between 1-6 and the comparison and options will be static no matter what filter type you have chosen from the drop down

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do :/ What do you mean by the columns on the left? Could you give a little more context?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use an accordion/step-like flow. The user would select the filter in step 1 and each accordion/step section has means allowing the user to go to next (or previous) sections.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rmardeni/NDncE/49/ (I didn't create this, just Googled it)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you can either provide a default value of the combo-box with the filter most of your users are going to use, (e.g. like To and From date if this is some ticketing site). You can also have a not-selected drop down that enforces user to select a value before you show next options to the user. This is useful when you want user to make a conscious and explicit choice.

Currently your view involves accordions. I do know exact purpose of including that as that component is taking much of your real estate which can be used in a better way. I can have a small box which has filter selection combo followed by single value or multiple value selection choices and a bigger content area to show the results.

If I am correct then you are building a filter which can make use of deferred create. Currently, your form is not telling me what I am filtering. I mean Interval of X and Y *of what*? Amount, date, locations? You can include that information at the top of your form too.